# Delete all images in a folder except those with defined string in title?

Tags: macos, terminal, automator

I have around 50,000 images in a folder (I'm using Mac OSX), and I'd like to delete all of them unless they have **x300** or **300x** in them. I was hoping it's possible using the terminal or automator, but haven't a clue where how to do it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With terminal, there are many ways to do this. One option is to use [find](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)(1):

```
find /your/dir -type f \! -name 'x300' \! -name '300x' -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

Replace `/your/dir` with the location where your files lie. Once you're absolutely sure the [find](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) command hits only those files you actually want to delete with [rm](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html), remove "echo" from the exec-part and re-execute to actually remove files instead of printing out which files would be removed.

Some explanations:
find /your/dir finds all files and folders in /your/diir ans below.
-type f filters to only files
-name `x300` filter to only things containing x300 in the filename.
The ! reverses this (so only files NOT containing).

-exec executes a command. You can exec echo, or you could `-print` them.
You can use rm as command to delete, or `-delete` to use finds building.

`{}` is the current filename. If you use `\;` then {} will get replaced by one filename at a time. (so if you have 10000 files to remove it will start a new rm 10000 times).

You can also replace that with `+` to get a lot of files in one go (though -delete is even more efficient).

Comment: Howdy! Thanks ever so much for your answer, I've been trying to get it to work (and figure it out for myself!) but It's not behaving how I think it should..., I'm using the command **find /Users/Carl/Desktop/LTW -type f \! -name 'x300' \! -name '300x' -exec echo rm -f {} \;** but that's returning all the files from what i can see, for example, the terminal has echoed **rm -f /Users/Carl/Desktop/LTW/zz-top-texicali-ep-review-300x225.jpg** which it should exclude because of the **300x225** right? Can you spot where I'm being dumb? Thanks in advance!